# gtts module not found even though 'Requirement already satisfied'

Tags: python

Im using vs code to try and make my own little virtual assistant. I've installed playsound and gtts along with others but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried installing it again but it just keeps saying that the requirement is already satisfied. I've tried using pip and pip3 but the same thing happens. When i do pip list it comes up with different things including gtts and playsound. Im using windows 10 and have tried everything.

from gtts import gTTS

import playsound

from datetime import datetime

import time

from googlesearch import search

*the error*

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I made it like below

1. install python 3.10.8 64-bit
2. Click python version around bottom right on the blue status bar in VS code
3. If you have a couple of python version, switch to python 64-bit from 32-bit.

or
pip uninstall gTTS and then pip install gTTS again.

I hope my suggestion will be helpful.